# How do I extract a LinkedListNode<T> from a LinkedList<T>

Tags: c#, casting, linked-list, .net-3.0

I have a LinkedList that I am using to track consecutive numbers that are sent to this class. (I ultimately want to find the missing numbers).

I now need to use the method [ranges.AddAfter(recentNode,someNewNode)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hxfc7s5%28v=vs.80%29), but I can't do it by casting.  What am I missing?

```
class ContiguousData 
{
    LinkedList<ContiguousDataValue> ranges = new LinkedList<ContiguousDataValue>();

    public void AddValue(int val)
    {
        LinkedListNode<ContiguousDataValue> recentNode = null;

        foreach (var range in ranges)
        {
            if (val > range.UpperInt)
            {
                if (val == range.UpperInt + 1)
                    range.UpperInt = val;
                else
                {
                    if (recentNode == null)
                        ranges.AddFirst(new ContiguousDataValue() { UpperInt = val, LowerInt = val });
                    else
                        ranges.AddAfter(recentNode, new ContiguousDataValue() { UpperInt = val, LowerInt = val });
                }
                break;
            }
            else if (val < range.LowerInt)
            {
                if (val == range.LowerInt - 1)
                    range.LowerInt = val;
                else
                {
                    // do  more logic (incomplete)
                }
            }

           // Compiler error
            recentNode = (LinkedListNode<ContiguousDataValue>)range;
        }

        if (ranges.Count == 0)
        {
            ranges.AddFirst(new ContiguousDataValue() { UpperInt = val, LowerInt = val });
            return;
        }
    }

    internal class ContiguousDataValue
    {
        public int UpperInt { get; set; }
        public int LowerInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Since casting doesn't work, how do I convert `range` to a `LinkedListNode<T>`?

Comment: Suppose you have the node. What you expect to do with it?

Comment: My intent is to do `ranges.AddAfter(recentNode, something)`

Comment: @makerofthings7: For starters, that is not going to work during an enumeration.

Comment: @makerofthings7: Looking at the MSDN docs, it appears you want a something to iterate over the nodes instead of the values. Something like the `Find` and `FindLast` methods? Except not quite.

Comment: @leppie - I think Find will do it.  Perhaps my class of T needs to have something implemented  ICompareable<T>?

Comment: First off, if you want to iterate through the nodes, you have to use the actual links of the LinkedList (ranges.First, range.Next etc.). LinkedList implements IEnumerable<T>, not IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> so the objects you are iterating through have no relation to the other nodes. Second, what you are doing would technically modify a collection while it is iterating that collection and that'll throw an error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are looking for;

```
var ranges = new LinkedList<ContiguousDataValue>();

for (var recentNode = ranges.First;
     recentNode != null;
     recentNode = recentNode.Next)
{
  var range = recentNode.Value; 
  ranges.AddAfter(recentNode,someNewNode);
}
```

Comment: I expanded the code in my question.  I'm using a linked list to identify contiguous number ranges sent out of order  (but mostly in increasing order).  I'll have to think if this can help.

Comment: `Find` should work if all the values are unique, but hardly efficient.

Comment: @makerofthings7: I slightly modified the example, so you can use it as a drop in replacement for `foreach`.

Comment: Aahh, so a for loop allows the better casting, and a foreach is only for type of T.  Leppie, is it common for a "foreach" type to differ from the type returned in the "for" loop?